# wget: identify broken outbound links

Tags: wget

`wget`'s `--spider` option makes it straightforward to identify broken internal links:

```
wget --spider --recursive --level=0 mywebsite.com
```

I tried to extend that to look for broken outbound links with `-H` but since (as far as I can tell) you can't specify an additional recursion level on external domains, leaving in `--level=0` lets the spider loose over the entire world wide web.

One workaround I could think of is using the website's `sitemap.xml` (when available) to get the entire set of URLs for the domain and feeding them back to `wget`, so I can limit the crawl depth:

```
wget -O - https://mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml \
| hred -xcr loc@.textContent \
| wget -i - -H --spider --recursive --level 1
```

This setup uses the separate tool [`hred`](https://github.com/danburzo/hred) to extract URLs from the XML.

Is there a more efficient way to find broken external links with `wget`? By either making it work with the sitemap natively or, ideally, without depending on that XML to exist.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to reading from `sitemap.xml` directly, this seems to be a new feature in [`wget2`](https://github.com/rockdaboot/wget2):

> - Support scanning URLs from local Sitemap XML file (`--force-sitemap -i <filename>`)

To produce a flat list of all URLs in a website with `wget` in the absence of a sitemap, we can crawl the website and extract the URLs with a grep-like tool from `wget`s output:

```bash
wget --spider -r mywebsite.com 2>&1 \
| rg '^--.+-- (.+)$' --replace '$1' \
| sort -u
```

Wget is probably not the best tool for the job, but it's workable.